# Tiny mce image edit delete

Tags: jquery, plugins, tinymce

Is there any tinymce or jquery plugins for edit/delete image in tinymce (Same as wordpress tinymce) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the plugin called [imagemanager](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/plugins.php), but this one is not a free plugin owned by moxiecode - the creators of tinymce.

But you are free to create your own plugin with that functionality, but that's a lot of work.

Comment: I had done tinymce advance with my own since i need context menu option same as word press tinymce advance for images. Is there any possible plugins to create as like wordpress contex menu.